# saving spark rdd in ORC format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, orc

I am trying to save my RDD in orc format.

```
  val data: RDD[MyObject] = createMyData()
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  import sqlContext.implicits._
  data.toDF.write.format("orc").save(outputPath)
```

It compiles fine but it doesn't work. 
I get following exception:

```
 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: The ORC data source can only be used with HiveContext.
 java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: The ORC data source can only be used with HiveContext.
```

I would like to avoid using hive to do this, because my data is in hdfs and it is not related to any hive table. Is there any workaround?
It works fine for Parquet format.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Persisting ORC formats in persistent storage area (like HDFS) is only available with the HiveContext.

As an alternate (workaround) you can register it as temporary table. Something like this: -

```
DataFrame.write.mode("overwrite").orc("myDF.orc")
val orcDF = sqlCtx.read.orc("myDF.orc")
orcDF.registerTempTable("<Table Name>")
```

Comment: yeah i know this workaround but as I said i really don't want to use HiveContext. anyway thanks

Comment: @homar it can't be done without a HiveContext

Answer (score 1):

As for now, saving as orc can only be done with HiveContext.

so the approach will be like this :

```
import sqlContext.implicits._ 
val data: RDD[MyObject] = createMyData()
val sqlContext = new New Org.Apache.Spark.Sql.Hive.HiveContext(Sc)   
data.toDF.write.format("orc").save(outputPath)
```